# C program to return a histogram can't proceed after asking for user input

Tags: c, scanf, histogram

The goal of the program is to return a histogram counting the number of occurrences of values in the data array which has num_elts members. However, it is stuck at collecting user input.

```
int *make_hist(int data[], int num_elts, int maxval) {
  int *hist = (int *)malloc(maxval * sizeof(int));
  int i = 0;
  while (i <= num_elts) {
    int val = data[i];
    if (val >= 0 && val <= maxval) {
      hist[val]++;
    }
  }
  return hist;
}

int main(void) {
  int values[20];
  printf("enter 20 integer values in the range 0-10\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &values[i]);
  }
  int *result = make_hist(values, 20, 10);
  printf("occurrences:\n");

  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    printf("%d: %d\n", i, result[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (i <= num_elts) {` Neither value changes in the loop so it will never end. You probably want `i++` in there. Or use a `for` loop: `for (int i = 0; i < num_elts; i++) {`

Comment: Also note: `malloc` will not clear the array so you can start with a bunch of junk values in `hist`. Use `calloc`, `memset`, or a `for` loop to initialize all elements of the array to `0`.

Comment: And, `if (val >= 0 && val <= maxval) {` could result in writing past the end of the array if `vall == maxval`. Use `if (val >= 0 && val < maxval) {`

Comment: Don't forget to release the memory that you reserved using `malloc` with function `free(result);` in the main function.

Comment: And also I think that here `int *hist = (int *)malloc(maxval * sizeof(int));` you are making an array of 10 int elements instead of 20 like you wanted. Consider changing the parameter from `maxval` to `num_elts` because that is the int where you are passing the actual number of elements for the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop in your `int *make_hist(int data[], int num_elts, int maxval)` function, in the `while (i <= num_elts)` section. You are not changing the value of `i`, and therefore `i` (0) will always be less then `num_elets` (20). I recommend adding `++i` or `i++` before the end of your while loop to update it.

```
int *make_hist(int data[], int num_elts, int maxval) {
     int *hist = (int *)malloc(maxval * sizeof(int));
     int i = 0;
     while (i <= num_elts) {
        int val = data[i];
        if (val >= 0 && val <= maxval) {
           hist[val]++;
        }
        ++i;
     }
     return hist;
}
```